# Moodle ByPass Login Screen

Tags: moodle

I am trying to integrate Moodle into an existing website. I have the users sign into my website and have an option from there to jump into Moodle. I want to make it so the user doesn't have to enter a username and password.

I have created a plugin that should bypass this screen but it isn't working. I am not sure if I am missing something or the file is formatted incorrectly:

```
<?php

require_once($CFG->libdir.'/authlib.php');

class auth_plugin_sentry extends auth_plugin_base {

function auth_plugin_sentry() {
    $this->config = get_config('auth/sentry');
    $this->authtype = 'sentry';
}

// We don't acutally auth anyone, we're just here for the hooks
function user_login ($username, $password) {
    return true;
}

    function config_form($config, $err, $user_fields) {
    include 'config.php';
}
function process_config($config) {
    // set to defaults if undefined
    if (!isset($config->host)) {
        $config->host = 'localhost';
    }
    if (!isset($config->type)) {
        $config->type = 'mysql';
    }
    if (!isset($config->sybasequoting)) {
        $config->sybasequoting = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($config->name)) {
        $config->name = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->user)) {
        $config->user = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->pass)) {
        $config->pass = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->table)) {
        $config->table = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->fielduser)) {
        $config->fielduser = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->fieldpass)) {
        $config->fieldpass = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->passtype)) {
        $config->passtype = 'plaintext';
    }
    if (!isset($config->extencoding)) {
        $config->extencoding = 'utf-8';
    }
    if (!isset($config->setupsql)) {
        $config->setupsql = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->debugauthdb)) {
        $config->debugauthdb = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($config->removeuser)) {
        $config->removeuser = AUTH_REMOVEUSER_KEEP;
    }
    if (!isset($config->changepasswordurl)) {
        $config->changepasswordurl = '';
    }

    // Save settings.
    set_config('host',          $config->host,          'auth/db');
    set_config('type',          $config->type,          'auth/db');
    set_config('sybasequoting', $config->sybasequoting, 'auth/db');
    set_config('name',          $config->name,          'auth/db');
    set_config('user',          $config->user,          'auth/db');
    set_config('pass',          $config->pass,          'auth/db');
    set_config('table',         $config->table,         'auth/db');
    set_config('fielduser',     $config->fielduser,     'auth/db');
    set_config('fieldpass',     $config->fieldpass,     'auth/db');
    set_config('passtype',      $config->passtype,      'auth/db');
    set_config('extencoding',   trim($config->extencoding), 'auth/db');
    set_config('setupsql',      trim($config->setupsql),'auth/db');
    set_config('debugauthdb',   $config->debugauthdb,   'auth/db');
    set_config('removeuser',    $config->removeuser,    'auth/db');
    set_config('changepasswordurl', trim($config->changepasswordurl), 'auth/db');

    return true;
}

}

?>
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have already been through the wiki for creating an auth plugin? http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Authentication_plugins

I'm wondering if its enabled though?

In site admin -> plugins -> authentication

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Managing_authentication

Comment: I have looked over the documentation for creating and enabling a plugin but it is still not working. I can go into my authentication plugins and see that mine is enabled but I am still getting the login screen.

Comment: Not sure if I can help any further but you might want to look at the source of some of the integration plugins - http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Integrations

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. I needed to call the loginpage_hook function. I am now grabbing the user and password from a cookie and sending it to authenticate_user_login to validate.

```
<?php

require_once($CFG->libdir.'/authlib.php');

class auth_plugin_sentry extends auth_plugin_base {

function auth_plugin_sentry() {
    $this->config = get_config('auth/sentry');
    $this->authtype = 'sentry';
}
function user_login($username, $password) {
    return false;
}

/**
 * Authentication hook - is called every time user hit the login page
 */
function loginpage_hook() {
    global $USER, $SESSION, $CFG, $DB;

    $username = $_COOKIE['STARUSER'];
    $password = $_COOKIE['STARPASS'];

    //$username = "admin";//$user->username;
    //$password = "Admin123!";

    //authenticate the user
    $user = authenticate_user_login($username, $password);
    if ($user) {
        complete_user_login($user);
        // Redirection
        // No wantsurl stored or external - go to homepage
        $urltogo = $CFG->wwwroot.'/';
        redirect($urltogo);
    }
    else
    {
        //if user authorize fails bounce back to user student portal with error
        header("Location: xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
}

function config_form($config, $err, $user_fields) {
    include 'config.php';
}
function process_config($config) {
    // set to defaults if undefined
    if (!isset($config->host)) {
        $config->host = 'localhost';
    }
    if (!isset($config->type)) {
        $config->type = 'mysql';
    }
    if (!isset($config->sybasequoting)) {
        $config->sybasequoting = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($config->name)) {
        $config->name = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->user)) {
        $config->user = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->pass)) {
        $config->pass = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->table)) {
        $config->table = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->fielduser)) {
        $config->fielduser = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->fieldpass)) {
        $config->fieldpass = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->passtype)) {
        $config->passtype = 'plaintext';
    }
    if (!isset($config->extencoding)) {
        $config->extencoding = 'utf-8';
    }
    if (!isset($config->setupsql)) {
        $config->setupsql = '';
    }
    if (!isset($config->debugauthdb)) {
        $config->debugauthdb = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($config->removeuser)) {
        $config->removeuser = AUTH_REMOVEUSER_KEEP;
    }
    if (!isset($config->changepasswordurl)) {
        $config->changepasswordurl = '';
    }

    // Save settings.
    set_config('host',          $config->host,          'auth/db');
    set_config('type',          $config->type,          'auth/db');
    set_config('sybasequoting', $config->sybasequoting, 'auth/db');
    set_config('name',          $config->name,          'auth/db');
    set_config('user',          $config->user,          'auth/db');
    set_config('pass',          $config->pass,          'auth/db');
    set_config('table',         $config->table,         'auth/db');
    set_config('fielduser',     $config->fielduser,     'auth/db');
    set_config('fieldpass',     $config->fieldpass,     'auth/db');
    set_config('passtype',      $config->passtype,      'auth/db');
    set_config('extencoding',   trim($config->extencoding), 'auth/db');
    set_config('setupsql',      trim($config->setupsql),'auth/db');
    set_config('debugauthdb',   $config->debugauthdb,   'auth/db');
    set_config('removeuser',    $config->removeuser,    'auth/db');
    set_config('changepasswordurl', trim($config->changepasswordurl), 'auth/db');

    return true;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: Super! Glad you go it sorted.